# Script PHP para contar registros separados por virgulas

Tags: php, mysql, array, contador

No bando de dados eu tenho uma coluna que recebe strings nesse formato: ["87","12","67"]

O que eu preciso é contar cada valor separado por virgula e atribuir a alguma variável, lembrando que existem mais linhas. Nesse caso eu teria uma variável com o valor 3.

Meu código não evoluiu muito, mas creio que esse seja o caminho:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

$banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao,'bd');

mysqli_set_charset($conexao,'utf8');

$res = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT  replace(replace(coluna,'[',''),']','') FROM tabela");

$var = array($res);

echo count($var);
```

Conto com a ajuda da comunidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O formato `["87","12","67"]` é um formato de JSON válido, então você pode usar o `json_decode`.

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao,'bd');
mysqli_set_charset($conexao,'utf8');

$res = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT coluna FROM tabela");

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
      echo "Quantidade: ". count(json_decode($r['coluna'], true));
}
```

Comment: +1, bem simples e direto